# Vue view update？

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Build A Single page app with vue 2 and vue-router 2

build.vue:

```
<style>
    #build-content {
        margin: 20px 20px;
    }
</style>
<template>
    <div id="build-content">
        <h2>title</h2>
        <div v-for="(buildValue, buildKey) in currentConfig">
            <li v-for="(value, key) in buildValue"
                is="build-item"
                v-bind:buildEventId="buildKey"
                v-bind:buildKey="key"
                v-bind:buildValue="value"
                v-on:remove="remove">
            </li>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import BuildItem from './build-item.vue'
    import Vue from "vue";
    import qs from 'qs';
    export default {
        components:{ BuildItem },
        data () {
            return {
                currentConfig: {
                    "1" : {
                        "akey" : "aValue",
                        "bkey" : "bValue",
                        "ckey" : "cValue",
                    },
                    "2" : {
                        "akey" : "aValue",
                        "bkey" : "bValue",
                        "ckey" : "cValue",
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            remove: function (eventId, key) {
                console.log(eventId + " " + key);
                Vue.delete(this.currentConfig[eventId], key);
            }
        },
        mounted: function () {

        }

    }
</script>
```

build-item.vue:

```
<style scoped>
    .tab {
        margin-right:2em
    }
</style>
<template>
    <div>
        <br>
        <span class="tab">event</span>
        <Input v-model="eventId" placeholder="input..." style="width: 150px" class="tab"/>
        <span class="tab">key:</span>
        <Input v-model="key" placeholder="input..." style="width: 200px" class="tab"/>
        <span class="tab">value:</span>
        <Input v-model="value" placeholder="input..." style="width: 300px" class="tab"/>
        <Button type="error" @click="remove">remove</Button>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                eventId: this.buildEventId,
                key: this.buildKey,
                value: this.buildValue,

            }
        },
        props: {
            buildEventId: {
              type: String
            },
            buildKey: {
                type: String
            },
            buildValue:{
                type: String
            }
        },
        methods: {
            remove: function () {
                this.$emit('remove', this.eventId, this.buildKey);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Click the first row of the list("1","akey","aValue')，but remove the third row("1","cKey","cValue") ，console.log output is correct，how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key

> This default mode is efficient, but only suitable when your list
> render output does not rely on child component state or temporary DOM
> state (e.g. form input values).

```
<div v-for="(buildValue, buildKey) in currentConfig" :key="buildKey">
     <li v-for="(value, key) in buildValue" :key="key"
           is="build-item"
           v-bind:buildEventId="buildKey"
           v-bind:buildKey="key"
           v-bind:buildValue="value"
           v-on:remove="remove">
     </li>
</div>
```

add `:key="buildKey"` and `:key="key"` ,Fixed the problem